# I can't read timeline anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I must read the timeline from user and the program work until yesterday. Today if I do this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/******/posts?access_token=*****
```

The post exists but the result is :

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

this is not correct because this call first show me all timeline from user but now is not work anymore. If I'm the user admin of app the program work. Anyone can help me?is there some problem with facebook?

Comment: Don't share access tokens with other people

Comment: So it does work for users that have a role in the app, but not for others? That most likely means that you did not submit your app for review yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have a look into the Facebook Developers documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens).

This could be the way to go:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/posts?key=value&access_token={your-access-token}
```

Does this solve your problem?